# How to observe activity presenter variables from fragment presenter?

Tags: android, rx-java, mvp, presenter

I am creating a weather application, the structure of which is as follows:
a single activity (host) and two fragments.
I need to implement it with the MVP architecture and using RxJava. When the app starts, the coordinates are calculated using GPS in the activity and will be stored in the activity presenter, but I can't figure out how to get latitude and longitude from the activity presenter to calculate the weather by coordinates.
If it was an MVVM architecture, I would just make a coordinate LiveData observer from the activity ViewModel and in the fragment ViewModel I would start getting data on them, but how to do this in MVP?

This is how I get the data using RxJava:

```
class WeatherPresenter @Inject constructor(
    private val view: WeatherContract.View,
    private val getWeatherUseCase: GetWeatherUseCase
) : WeatherContract.Presenter {

    override fun onViewCreated() {
        fetchWeather()
    }

    override fun fetchWeather() {
        val latitude = 53.893 // Must be obtained from activity presenter
        val longitude = 27.5674 // Must be obtained from activity presenter

        getWeatherUseCase(latitude, longitude)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe {
                view.showProgressBar()
            }
            .subscribe({ weather ->
                view.showWeather(weather)
                Timber.d("Getting weather continues")
            }, { error ->
                view.hideProgressBar()
                view.showErrorImage(if (error !is UnknownHostException) error.localizedMessage else null)
                Timber.d("Getting weather error: ${error.localizedMessage}")
            }, {
                view.hideProgressBar()
                Timber.d("Getting weather complete")
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're on MVP, you can use old interface callback pattern to communicate between host activity and it's fragment. Then from the callback, you can provide appropriate data to your fragment presenter.

Comment: Maybe non-related but you could use `doFinally` in order to hide the progress bar along with `.unsubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` though I would inject the main thread dispatcher to make the Presenter android agnostic